# How to set Get-Date format as variable but get up to date time in function

Tags: powershell, datetime, variables, path, variable-assignment

I'm trying to store a get-date format as a variable so it's at the top of the file but be able to have it get an up to date get-date in functions using the variable name. Example:

```
    $LogDir = "c:\somefolders"
    $LogSubDir = $(Get-Date -f MM-yyyy)
    function MakeLogSubDirs{
    $Path = "$LogDir\$LogSubDir" # rather than "$LogDir\$(Get-Date -f MM-yyyy)"
    If(!(test-path $path)) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $path
    }
```

But I don't want it to set the time in the variable, I want the variable in the variable, to get gotten in the function. I tried single quotes `$LogSubDir = '$(Get-Date -f MM-yyyy)'`, but that didn't work. `"$LogDir\$(Get-Date -f MM-yyyy)"` works to make the folder. Any suggestions?

Comment: so ... put the call for the date IN THE FUNCTION. [*grin*] that is what you are asking for ... i fail to see why you cannot do what you say you want.

Comment: it sounds like you want the timestamp to be the current time _at the time the timestamp is used_. if that is the case, the you need to create the timestamp when you use it in the function, not before the function  is triggered. ///// if that is not what you want, then PLEASE clarify what this ... _exquisitely confusing_ statement means >>> `But I don't want it to set the time in the variable, I want the variable in the variable, to get gotten in the function`

Comment: AHA! thank you for the clarification ... [*grin*] ///// to save the `format string` ... simply assign it to a $Var and use that $Var in your call to get the date. code here is icky, so i will make an Answer with a demo of the idea.

Answer (score 0):

here is a demo of the `save the pattern into a $Var & use that later` idea ... [*grin*]

```
$EU_Backwards = 'dd-MM-yyyy'
$US_InsideOut = 'MM-dd-yyyy'
$SaneSortable = 'yyyy-MM-dd'

Get-Date -Format $EU_Backwards
```

output = `15-05-2022`

---

as an aside, try to use the sane, sortable `largest 1st` layout whenever you can. [*grin*]

Comment: @Retrotube - you are welcome! [*grin*] one point ... you have `:` chars in your timestamps - and those are not legal in file names. you likely otta stick with hyphens, instead.